# Gradle build.gradle to Maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, gradle, pom.xml

I have a Gradle project and I need all its dependencies to be transferred and used with another Maven project. In other words how can I generate (or can I generate) the pom.xml from the build.gradle?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most built in solution would likely be to use the `archiveTask` task in the Maven Plugin which will generate a pom in the `poms` folder in your build dir. http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sec:maven_pom_generation

Comment: I an referencing the maven plugin, but have no `archiveTask` task.

Answer (score 94):

Since Gradle 7, when using [Gradle's Maven-Publish plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html), *publishToMavenLocal* and *publish* are automatically added to your tasks, and calling either will always generate a POM file.

So if your *build.gradle* file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
    runtimeOnly group: 'ch.qos.logback', name:'logback-classic', version:'1.2.3'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

// the GAV of the generated POM can be set here
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'edu.bbte.gradleex.mavenplugin'
            artifactId = 'gradleex-mavenplugin'
            version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

you can call `gradle publishToLocalRepo` in its folder, you will find in the *build/publications/maven* subfolder, a file called *pom-default.xml*. Also, the built JAR together with the POM will be in your Maven local repo. More exactly the `gradle generatePomFileForMavenPublication` task does the actual generation, if you want to omit publication to your Maven local repo.

Please note that not all dependencies show up here, since the Gradle "configurations" don't always map one-to-one with Maven "scopes".

Comment: this should be the "official" way to generate POM and install artifacts locally, especially when you are converting a bunch of legacy POM based module projects.

Comment: Looks like this snippet of code is nicely copied around the web, I wonder who was the original author https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-convert-maven-to-gradle-and-vice-versa

Comment: As of Gradle 7.x the [maven plugin has been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100888/plugin-with-id-maven-not-found). `maven-publish` should be used instead

Comment: @pirateofebay True, thanks. Adapted the answer to reflect the new syntax.

Comment: The generated pom.xml is kinda broken though : no Java version is specified, or no encoding either.

Answer (score 25):

As I didn't want to install anything in my local repo, I did following, instead, after reading docs.
Add in your build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.company.root'
// artifactId is taken by default, from folder name
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

task writeNewPom << {
    pom {
        project {
            inceptionYear '2014'
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("pom.xml")
}
```

to run it
    `gradle writeNewPom`

@a_horse_with_no_name

gradle being made with groovy can try to add
after ending } project block

```
build{
  plugins{
    plugin{
      groupId 'org.apache.maven.plugins'
      artifactId 'maven-compiler-plugin'
      configuration{
          source '1.8'
          target '1.8'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

didn't try, wild guess !

Comment: This only writes the JARs into the POM, but doesn't create a complete project that also includes the sources from the project. How do I get the maven plugin to also write the source (and text, resources...) directories into the POM?

Comment: If this fails with "Could not find method leftShift() for", then replace the `<<` operator with `doLast` and try again. Used with a [similar approach I found here](https://gist.github.com/jmruc/5852692)

Comment: This is no longer supported: The pom() method was provided by the legacy maven plugin. Since this plugin has been removed in Gradle 7, the method is no longer available. The maven plugin was replaced by the maven-publish plugin, which does not provide a comparable replacement for pom(). The maven-publish plugin automatically creates pom generation tasks based on the configured publications.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:tasks 7

Answer (score 20):

When you have no gradle installed the "write gradle task to do this" is not very userful. Instead of installing this 100MB beast with dependecies I made the filter converting gradle dependencies to maven dependencies:

```
cat build.gradle\
| awk '{$1=$1};1'\
| grep -i "compile "\
| sed -e "s/^compile //Ig" -e "s/^testCompile //Ig"\
| sed -e "s/\/\/.*//g"\
| sed -e "s/files(.*//g"\
| grep -v ^$\
| tr -d "'"\
| sed -e "s/\([-_[:alnum:]\.]*\):\([-_[:alnum:]\.]*\):\([-+_[:alnum:]\.]*\)/<dependency>\n\t<groupId>\1<\/groupId>\n\t<artifactId>\2<\/artifactId>\n\t<version>\3<\/version>\n<\/dependency>/g"
```

This converts

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.+'
compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.+'
compile 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.3'
```

into

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.+</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.+</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

The rest of pom.xml should be created by hand.

Comment: To convert gradle2maven or maven2gradle dependencies you can use this online service https://sagioto.github.io/maven2gradle/

Comment: @YoandyPérezVillazón it is for maven2gradle only and not vice versa?

Comment: @IlyaYevlampiev sorry, only mvn2gradle !

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `build.gradle` file.  I pasted it to the end of mine:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'java'

task writeNewPom doLast {
    pom {
        project {
            groupId 'org.example'
            artifactId 'test'
            version '1.0.0'
        
            inceptionYear '2008'
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("$buildDir/newpom.xml")
}
```

Then run the following depending on which you have

```
$ gradle writeNewPom
```

or

```
$ /.gradlew writeNewPom
```

The file is generated and put in `$buildDir/newpom.xml`
Snagged [from this gist](https://gist.github.com/jmruc/5852692)