# maven plugin to generate pom.xml

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio

Hi I have a gradle android project that contains two library modules:

```
- MyProject
|-- LibA
|-- LibB
```

So LibB has a dependency to LibA. So the build.gradle file for LibB looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://$buildDir/repo")
            pom.groupId = 'com.test.lib'
            pom.version = '1.0'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile project (':LibA')
}
```

As you see I would like to generate .aar files for each of my libraries modules in my gradle project. So far so good, but generating the pom.xml file with the correct dependency to LibA does not work like expected:

The pom.xml file for LibB looks like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
  <version>19.+</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>MyProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>LibA</artifactId>
  <version>unspecified</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Is there a way to specify how the maven dependency for LibA should look like in the generated pom file.
How does other projects like ActionBar-PullToRefresh do that? For instance: ActionBar-PullToRefresh has an sub library module for Actionbar sherlock which has a dependency to :library
 [the mail ActionBar-PullToRefresh library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/blob/master/extras/actionbarsherlock/build.gradle)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Looks similar to [Gradle build.gradle to Maven pom.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888490/gradle-build-gradle-to-maven-pom-xml)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really into gradle, but I'd not use a dependency that points directly to the other project, but rather one that defines the group and artifact ids and the version of the artifact, like you do with the android support library.

So not

```
 compile project (':LibA')
```

But rather

```
 compile ('com.example.lib:LibA:1.2')
```

Edit: previously stated "compile project ('com.example.lib:LibA:1.2')", which was wrong. Thanks to Blundell to point that out.

Comment: you can't declare a dependency on a local module i.e. `LibA` with a group & version, it's inherently unversioned