# Run cucumber test with cached dependencies and plugins on gradle

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber

Hi I want to run a few test made with cucumber on a gradle project, I was trying to run this test's on another PC (with limited network access) so I copy/pasted everything that was under `~./gradle/caches` and the project files like `build, src and build.gradle` and placed everything on the same place as the original

So once I got everything in place I ran this

```
  gradle --no-daemon --offline cucumber
```

And I get a failure

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download gradle-cucumber-plugin.jar (com.github.samueltbrown:gradle-cucumber-plugin:0.9): No cached version available for offline mode
```

The odd thing is that I have the file on the caches directory

```
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.samueltbrown/gradle-cucumber-plugin/0.9/7b65c67654715025eed1924
0c4f7defbef9645e0# ls
gradle-cucumber-plugin-0.9.jar
```

FYI, I don't have the kind of experience with gradle/java as I would like so any kind of suggestion would be great, this is where the plugin is "required" on the build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id "com.github.samueltbrown.cucumber" version "0.9"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this open [Gradle issue](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2690)

Gradle cache isn't exactly portable currently. It does work, if the absolute path of the .gradle folder is exactly the same on both machines. The absolute path of `~/.gradle` is not the same if the username on both machines is different!

There are a few ways you can get around this, in order of effort required, least to most:

#### 1. Run without `--offline` *once*

If this is possible on your network limited machine, run without offline flag once, the dependencies will not be downloaded again, but checksums are - and more importantly the cache is now validated and suitable for use with the `--offline` flag.

#### 2. Move `.gradle` to a repeatable path

Move gradle cache folder to something like `/tmp/.gradle` by setting `GRADLE_USER_HOME` on both machines and then copy gradle cache between machines.

#### 3. Export all dependencies to a local folder

On the network connected machine, use a gradle task to export all dependencies to a filesystem folder. Copy the folder over to the other machine, and use a flatdir repo on the second machine.

```
repositories {
  flatDir {
    dirs 'lib' //folder containing dependencies
  }
}
```

(You could also export to a maven format repo instead of flatdir. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13396776/1174024)

#### 4. Use a maven cache instead

In my experience Maven's .m2 folder is far more portable. Create a maven project with the same dependencies, cache dependencies into .m2 and then copy .m2 over to the second machine. On the second machine add `mavenLocal()` as a repo.

Comment: Thanks I'll try what you suggested

Comment: Thank you with the second step was enough, I was running this inside a docker container and it worked like a charm

Comment: How can I run gradle --offline from Android studio?