# What does the random string mean as sub directory names in gradle cache directory which looks like MD5 code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio to develop android apps recently and most differently from `Eclipse`, it uses gradle as build tools. `Gradle` is really handy of course, I don't need to download jar and put it into libs folder anymore, `gradle` will download all dependencies i need for me and cache them in my laptop. For exmaple, `OkHttp` cache file will be somewhere like this:

```
C:\Users\tony\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okhttp\okhttp\2.6.0\212387a39088ecd3daff8e3bfc3bdc4123e33c67
```

Now I'm just confused about the final part. What does the directory means named as `212387a39088ecd3daff8e3bfc3bdc4123e33c67`. How does `gradle` generating it and the generating rules? Cause i found when i copy the cache files to another laptop it won't work. `Gradle` will download all of them again and generate another random directory name. Hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `How does gradle generating it and the generating rules?` what do you want to know it for? it is gradle's internal implementation that can change at any version change

Comment: Cause i have a PC which can't connect to Internet. Forbidden by company, which i couldn't download dependencies online. So i wanna copy these cache files from my laptop to this PC directly instead of download them online. But it seems not work, so i guess it might be some generating rules in this PC that gradle finds a different directory. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alpha-numeric string is the dependency file's SHA1 checksum. From gradle [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html):

> The storage path for a downloaded artifact includes the SHA1 checksum, meaning that 2 artifacts with the same name but different content can easily be cached.

If you're looking for how to move gradle cache between computers, see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34973244/745574