# Error while building Gradle project in Android Studio on offline Ubuntu 14.04 computer

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, gradle, offline

I have an offline computer that must never go online which has a gradle project on Android Studio. I was able to successfully build it and run it smoothly, but recent events made me change my username on the Ubuntu computer. That was done using 'usermod' and changing the home directory path, and all was successful.

When I now try to build the project, I get this error:

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not download hamcrest-core.jar (org.hamcrest:hamcrest=core:1.3)
>   Could not get resource
>   'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest=core.jar'.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest=core.jar'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com: unknown error

I believe this error means that it cannot connect to this site and download hamcrest. But, the hamcrest files already exist in the .gradle/ directory. And as I said, everything built successfully before I changed my name.

My solution might be old pathways that still exist, or changing a gradle file.
I have also tried to clean and rebuild project, and clear cache/restart the program to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: changing the file location of gradle cache invalidates it. Changing your usename effectively changes your gradle cache path (default location ~/.gradle)

Comment: For some ideas about getting around the offline computer problem, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34973244/745574