# Build android gradle application with command line

Tags: android, gradle, cmd, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I'm trying to build an android application with command line by using offline pc (I don't want to connect it to internet), so I open command prompt and I run the command

> gradlew.bat assembleRelease

But I get this error message[image: Commad line output]

I think that com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0 cannot be download because as I say

> my computer was offline and I don't want to connect it to internet

I downloaded gradle-1.3.0.jar and gradle-1.3.0.pom but I don't know where to place these files in order to build successfully without connectin to internet

Comment: gradle local cache is a bit tricky to move to an offline machine, but can be done. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34973244/745574