# Migrate the gradle cache instead of downloading it all from the Nexus?

Tags: java, caching, gradle, build, dependencies

In gradle, the downloading of the cache takes forever for us. It grabs from a nexus instance we host which has lots of jars on it.

This means that downloading the jars on the first build takes over an hour.

Is there a way I can load a .gradle folder all pre-loaded so it can skip this long download step for the first build? Is it as easy as finding a developer with the build's dependencies already cached and then zip up and send our the `.gradle` folder?

Comment: Gradle cache isn't really portable. [See issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1338), but there are a few workarounds you can try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968042/run-cucumber-test-with-cached-dependencies-and-plugins-on-gradle/34973244#34973244

Comment: Yeah i think this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968042/run-cucumber-test-with-cached-dependencies-and-plugins-on-gradle/34973244#34973244