# Import or use Android Studio projects in Codenvy IDE

Tags: android, android-studio, codenvy

I am trying to use `Codenvy` to `develop`, and I am switching from `Android Studio`. I am in the `middle` of a `project`. How can I `transition`? Can I use a `special import feature`? I have already tried to copy and paste the code, but a lot of libraries don't seem to be there. If you need to take a look at my `source code`, then just search up `"calc-nigma"` in `Github` search and you can click on the option that is made by `beekaydev`. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: First you import project into eclips and test code... after this you can import in android

Comment: @Javacoder I'm sorry but what are you talking about?

Comment: 1-First you import your project in android eclipse and run the code. 2-if code is runing than you can import into android studio..

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is not with your code but the dependencies Codenvy is using is Maven while it seems that your application may be using Gradle dependencies.

For the Support of Answer:

1. Maven uses `pom.xml` file to build your project.
2. Gradle uses `build.gradle` file to build the project.

If you want to move your project to **Codenvy** try migrating your Gradle build to Maven build using this thread [Migrating Gradle build.gradle to Maven pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888490/gradle-build-gradle-to-maven-pom-xml).

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Is there a feature in Android Studio for this? If there is, will I be able to copy and paste the result into Codenvy?

Comment: No Pal, there is no such feature available in Android Studio.

Comment: are there any easier solutions. It doesnt seem to be working for me. I am okay with an alternative that involves codenvy and has gradle too.