# Build Android project with maven

Tags: android, maven, android-support-library

My client asked me to make my existing android app buildable with maven.
I tried generating a pom.xml using the maven plugin , but unfortunately it doesn't map the dependencies. (Tried all solutions from here: [Gradle build.gradle to Maven pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888490/gradle-build-gradle-to-maven-pom-xml))

After that I tried writing the pom.xml myself , but maven cannot find the support libraries nor the google play ones:

> Failed to execute goal on project xxx: Could not resolve dependencies
>   for project  xxx.yyy:z:jar:1.0.0: The following artifacts could not be
>   resolved:  com.android.support:support-v13:jar:25.3.1, 
>   com.android.support:design:jar:25.3.1, 
>   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:jar:25.3.1, 
>   com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:jar:25.3.1, 
>   com.android.support:cardview-v7:jar:25.3.1, 
>   com.android.support:support-v4:jar:25.3.1, 
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:jar:11.0.2,
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:jar:11.0.2, 
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:jar:11.0.2:

My pom.xml entries look like this:

```
...
 <dependency>
   <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
   <artifactId>design</artifactId>
   <version>25.3.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
   <artifactId>appcompat-v7</artifactId>
   <version>25.3.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
   <artifactId>recyclerview-v7</artifactId>
   <version>25.3.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
   <artifactId>cardview-v7</artifactId>
   <version>25.3.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
   <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
   <version>25.3.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
...
```

If someone can guide me how to convert the support libraries into maven dependencies (automatically or manually) , that would be helpful.