# Developing java 11 google cloud functions in android studio

Tags: android, maven, gradle, google-cloud-functions, cloud

Now that we can develop google cloud functions with java runtime (or Scala or Groovy).
Anybody using android studio to develop google cloud function  using android studio?

- If you have a standard build.gradle please post.
- Is there a way to auto create pom.xml from gradle build.
- can we provision cloud function from within android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Most of this information is already available in the Cloud Functions documentation.

- There is a tutotial, [available here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-java#gradle_1), that offers an example `build.gradle` for a sample project, you can build on top of that one for your project's needs.
- According to this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12888558/12857703), you can use the `archiveTask` task in the Maven Plugin so that a `pom.xml` file is generated and stored in the `<buildDir>/poms` directory of your project.
- Unfortunately this is not possible. As you can see in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying#deployment):

> You can deploy Cloud Functions from your local machine, from your GitHub or Bitbucket source repository (via Cloud Source Repositories), or from the Cloud Functions API directly.

**NOTE**: For deployment from the local machine if you follow through the referring documentation you will see that this only applies to a deploy using the gcloud command-line tool

Comment: @Bakavani Do you find the answer above helpful?

Comment: Thank you @Rafael, I did read the functions docs, my intention of asking for a standard build.gradle is if someone has written a build.gradle that generates pom.xml or as part of build process generates shaded jar (or with manifest) file that can be provisioned on cloud easily :)

I'll try the archiveTask approach when I get some time and update.

Comment: Ok @Bakavani, once you get the time to test the proposed approach, and if it works, please remember to mark the answer as accepted so that others in the community can refer to this answer if they have a similar case to yours.